# how to know which framework using

Tags: asp.net, .net

When I am executing "dotnet new mvc -n MyWeb" command I am getting below code auto generated.

```
namespace MyWeb
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

Above code style is different than blog which I am following. The blog I am following shows below output. This is different than mine after executing same command. After googling, I knew it's due to difference in framework. 
How I can know which framework in use?
How I can force Visual Studio to use ASP.Net core 1.0

```
namespace secondapp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrol()
                .UseContentRool(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UserStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

                host.run()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Display .NET Core SDK version.

```
dotnet --version
```

> Display .NET Core information.

```
dotnet --info
```

> Create a new ASP.NET Core C# MVC application project in the current
>   directory with no authentication targeting .NET Core 1.0 (Specifies
>   the framework to target.  Values: `netcoreapp1.0` or `netcoreapp1.1`)

```
dotnet new mvc -au None -f netcoreapp1.0
```

Check the link for more details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore2x

Also from **Visual Studio** in **Solution Explorer** select your project and right click on it then select **Properties**, you will see the **Target framework** as below and you can change it.

[image]